# push the total amount of objects to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, count

I am trying to count how many times a specific item appears in an array. And then push that amount to an other array. I got the counter working, although when I push this amount to the array the type of this value turn out te be Not A Number...

Here is my code:

```
res2 = 
0: (2) [29682885, "Jean-Paul"]
1: (2) [29682886, "DEMO Martin"]
2: (2) [29682887, "Johan"]
3: (2) [29682892, "Peter"]
4: (2) [29682900, "Antoine"]
5: (2) [29682902, "Sandra"]
6: (2) [29682906, "Kevin"]
7: (2) [29682910, "Wouter"]
8: (2) [29682911, "Tom"]
9: (2) [4, "Autotask"]

res3 =
0: (2) [29682885, "2019-05-16T08:25:32Z"]
1: (2) [29682885, "2019-07-01T13:11:00Z"]
2: (2) [29682885, "2019-07-03T10:21:07Z"]
3: (2) [29682885, "2019-09-03T14:00:45Z"]
4: (2) [29682885, "2019-09-11T09:59:07Z"]
5: (2) [29682885, "2019-09-17T14:13:39Z"]
6: (2) [29682885, "2019-10-09T16:48:41Z"]
7: (2) [29682885, "2019-10-30T13:48:12Z"]
8: (2) [29682885, "2019-10-30T14:13:01Z"]
9: (2) [29682885, "2019-10-30T14:34:13Z"]
10: (2) [29682885, "2019-11-07T13:41:27Z"]
11: (2) [29682885, "2019-11-22T12:41:08Z"]
...

res2.sort();
res3.sort();

res3.forEach(sale => {
    res2.forEach(person => {
        if (sale[0] === person[0]) {
            if (person[1] === undefined) {
                person[1] = 1;
                console.log(person[1]);
            } else {
                person[1].occurrences++;
                console.log(person[1]);
               
                prepArray.push(person[1]);
            }
            prepArray.push(person[1]);
        }
    }); 
});
```

`prepArray.push(person[1]);` retruns an NaN somehow. But the console shows the exact amount I would like to push to my prepArray...

[image]

Comment: You should post what your data looks like. `push` does not return an item, but changes the array in place (since you said "returns").

Comment: I guess `person[1] = 1;` should be `person[1].occurrences = 1;` maybe? Or `person[1].occurrences++;` should be `person[1]++;`? Hard to tell without knowing what the input data looks like. Currently, this question is a candidate for getting closed, either due to a typo or due to "needs clarity". Please fix.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: I have added my input arrays, I hope this gives a little more clarity to my question.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the console output. The output you see is not "74 Jean-Paul", but 74 times the string "Jean-Paul".

Comment: @TostMaster That must be it. So creating a seperate counter would be the best solution?

Comment: That might do the trick. Just count them, and when you are done with counting, push the counter to the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used a mix of `filter`, `flat`, `map` to achieve this. Added code comments to explain what logic is being used.

```js
res2 = [[29682885, "Jean-Paul"],
[29682886, "DEMO Martin"],
[29682887, "Johan"],
[29682892, "Peter"],
[29682900, "Antoine"],
[29682902, "Sandra"],
[29682906, "Kevin"],
[29682910, "Wouter"],
[29682911, "Tom"],
[4, "Autotask"]]

res3 = [[29682885, "2019-05-16T08:25:32Z"],
[29682885, "2019-07-01T13:11:00Z"],
[29682902, "2019-07-03T10:21:07Z"],
[29682885, "2019-09-03T14:00:45Z"],
[29682885, "2019-09-11T09:59:07Z"],
[29682885, "2019-09-17T14:13:39Z"],
[29682902, "2019-10-09T16:48:41Z"],
[4, "2019-10-30T13:48:12Z"],
[4, "2019-10-30T14:13:01Z"],
[29682911, "2019-10-30T14:34:13Z"],
[29682911, "2019-11-07T13:41:27Z"],
[29682911, "2019-11-22T12:41:08Z"]];

// pick only the ids from res3
// this makes it easier for comparison
let res = res3.map(v => {
  return v.shift();
}).flat()

let final = [];

// loop over res2, and count occurrences using .filter().length
res2.map(sale => final.push([sale[1], res.filter(person => person === sale[0]).length]));

console.log(final);


// if you want the output as an object,
// you can do the following

let finalObj = {};

res2.map(sale => finalObj[sale[1]] = res.filter(person => person === sale[0]).length);

console.log({ finalObj })
```

I've modified the input set (`res3`) slightly to show the difference in counts, the above code outputs the following,

```
[
  [
    "Jean-Paul",
    5
  ],
  [
    "DEMO Martin",
    0
  ],
  [
    "Johan",
    0
  ],
  [
    "Peter",
    0
  ],
  [
    "Antoine",
    0
  ],
  [
    "Sandra",
    2
  ],
  [
    "Kevin",
    0
  ],
  [
    "Wouter",
    0
  ],
  [
    "Tom",
    3
  ],
  [
    "Autotask",
    2
  ]
]
```

Edited my answer to get the desired output in object format, so now you'll get,

```
{
    "Jean-Paul": 5,
    "DEMO Martin": 0,
    "Johan": 0,
    "Peter": 0,
    "Antoine": 0,
    "Sandra": 2,
    "Kevin": 0,
    "Wouter": 0,
    "Tom": 3,
    "Autotask": 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand many parts of your code, but trying to interpretate it:

```js
res2 = [
 [29682885, "Jean-Paul"],
 [29682886, "DEMO Martin"],
 [29682887, "Johan"],
 [29682892, "Peter"],
 [29682900, "Antoine"],
 [29682902, "Sandra"],
 [29682906, "Kevin"],
 [29682910, "Wouter"],
 [29682911, "Tom"],
 [4, "Autotask"],
];

res3 = [
 [29682911, "2019-05-16T08:25:32Z"],
 [29682885, "2019-07-01T13:11:00Z"],
 [29682902, "2019-07-03T10:21:07Z"],
 [29682885, "2019-09-03T14:00:45Z"],
 [29682885, "2019-09-11T09:59:07Z"],
 [29682902, "2019-09-17T14:13:39Z"],
 [29682885, "2019-10-09T16:48:41Z"],
 [29682885, "2019-10-30T13:48:12Z"],
 [29682885, "2019-10-30T14:13:01Z"],
 [29682885, "2019-10-30T14:34:13Z"],
 [29682911, "2019-11-07T13:41:27Z"],
 [29682911, "2019-11-22T12:41:08Z"]
]

res2.sort();
res3.sort();
const prepArray = {};
res3.forEach(sale => {
    res2.forEach(person => {
        if (sale[0] === person[0]) {
            if (person[1] === undefined) {
                person[1] = 1;
            } 
            prepArray[person[1]] = prepArray[person[1]] || 0;
            prepArray[person[1]] += 1;
        }
    }); 
});

console.log(prepArray)
```